# Conditional expectation of $X_1$ on $(X_1 + X_2)^2$

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, covariance

Given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ follow a normal distribution $N(\mu, \Sigma)$ whose mean and covariance are given by:

$\mu = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}
$,
$\Sigma = 
\begin{bmatrix}
4, -4 \\ 
-4, 8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Find $\mathbb{E}[X_1 | (X_1 + X_2)^2]$

How would I proceed with the square term: $(X_1 + X_2)^2$ in the condition?

Can I assume that it is also normally distributed?

Comment: you can't compute it without further information as the joint distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Maybe they are independent ?

Comment: @Surb : the joint distribution $(X_1;X_2)$ is full given in the text

Comment: @tommik: It's not so clear as written, $X_1$ and $X_2$ follow a normal law is not the same thing as $(X_1,X_2)$ follow a normal law... even if we can guess that the OP wants to say the latter one...

Comment: @Surb: $X_1$ and $X_2$ are normal variables where $X_1 \sim N(2, 4)$, $X_2 \sim N(1, 8)$, and Cov($X_1$, $X_2$) = -4 ($X_1$ and $X_2$ are not independent). Is that enough information?

Comment: Usually we are asked to compute the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X_1 | X_1 + X_2]$, which is readily solved using theory of normal correlation. In this case however I'm unsure how to approach the squared term inside the condition.

Comment: $f_{(X_1|(X_1+X_2)^2)}(x_1|(x_1 + x_2)^2) = \frac{f_{(X_1, (X_1 + X_2)^2)}(x_1 | (x_1 + x_2)^2)}{\int f_{(X_1, (X_1 + X_2)^2)} (s, (X_1 + X_2)^2) ds}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

- Denote $f_{X_1,X_2}$ the distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$
- Set $Z=(X_1+X_2)^2$. The distribution of $Z$ is given by $$f_Z(z)=\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d z}\left(\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{-\sqrt{z}-x_1}^{\sqrt {z}-x_1}f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)\,\mathrm d x_2\,\mathrm d x_1\right)\boldsymbol 1_{x>0}.$$ I let you do the calculation... I hope it's you'll find a closed form.
- The joint distribution of $Z$ and $X_1$ is given by $$f_{X_1,Z}(x_1,z)=\frac{1}{2z}\left(f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,\sqrt z-x_1)+f(x_1,-\sqrt z-x_1)\right)\boldsymbol 1_{z>0}.$$

Then $$\mathbb E[X_1\mid Z=z]=\int_{\mathbb R}x_1\frac{f_{X_1,Z}(x_1,z)}{f_Z(z)}\,\mathrm d x_1.$$

I would be very surprised if you can get a nice closed form.

Comment: how did you arrive at the joint distribution of $Z$ and $X_1$: $f_{(X_1,Z)}(x_1, z)$?

Comment: @mclovine: $f_{X_1,Z}(x_1,z)=\partial _{x}\partial _z\mathbb P\{X_1\leq x_1,Z\leq z\}$.

Comment: for ($X_1$ + $X_2$), I have its distribution $f_{X_1 + X_2}(x_1, x_2)$ as: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{\sigma_x^2+\sigma^2_y+2\rho\sigma_x\sigma_y}} \exp{(-\frac{(x+y)^2}{2(\sigma_x^2+\sigma^2_y+2\rho\sigma_x\sigma_y)})}$


Is this correct?

Comment: then for $Z = (X_1 + X_2)^2$, $f_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz} (...)$ would be...?

Comment: For the distribution of $X_1+X_2$, it's wrong. It should be $\int_{\mathbb R}f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x-x_1)dx_1$. And for $\frac{d}{dz}$ I let you do the calculation ;-) (you can permute the derivative and the first integral)@mclovine